# "SafariBookmarksSyncAgent quit unexpectedly" Keeps Popping Up and Cannot Open Safari

Tags: safari, crash

I updated safari to 11.1 yesterday and ever since it has been popping up the same message "SafariBookmarksSyncAgent quit unexpectedly" and it just continues to come back. I cant open Safari either because "Safari cannot be opened because of a problem".

I get following error in the log for both the Safari app and SafariBookmarksSyncAgent:

> Library not loaded:
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari
>
> Referenced from:
>   /System/Library/CoreServices/SafariSupport.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SafariBookmarksSyncAgent
>   Reason: no suitable image found.
>
> Did find:
>     /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari'
>
> /System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari:
>   code signature invalid for
>   '/System/Library/StagedFrameworks/Safari/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Safari'

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me was **restarting the computer in safe mode**.

Here's an explanation from an apple discussions post.

> Certain caches maintained by the system will be rebuilt.
>
> Safe mode is much slower to start up than normal. The next normal
>   startup may also be somewhat slow.
>
> When the login screen appears, restart as usual (not in safe mode) and
>   test. There's no need to log in while in safe mode.
>
> Note: If FileVault is enabled in OS X 10.9 or earlier, or if a
>   firmware password is set, or if the startup volume is a software RAID,
>   you can’t start in safe mode. In that case, ask for instructions.

From: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7069199